# Vectorize numpy assignment

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am assigning values to a numpy array by looking up values in other numpy arrays.  These arrays have potentially different indices.  Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
A=1; B=2; C=3; D=4; E=5
X = np.random.normal(0,1,(A,B,C,E))
Y = np.random.normal(0,1,(A,B,D))
Z = np.random.normal(0,1,(A,C))
Result = np.zeros((A,B,C,D,E))
for a in range(A):
    for b in range(B):
        for c in range(C):
            for d in range(D):
                for e in range(E):
                    Result[a,b,c,d,e] = Z[a,c] + Y[a,b,d] + X[a,b,c,e]
```

What is the best way to optimize this code?  I can remove the E for loop using Result[a,b,c,d,:] = Z[a,c] + Y[a,b,d] + X[a,b,c,:].  But then how to remove the rest of the loops?  I was also thinking that I could manipulate X,Y,Z before assignment so it merges easily with the dimensions of Result.  There must be more elegant ways.  Thanks for tips.

Comment: This is more of a codereview.stackexchange.com question. You should port it over there and see what optimization tips people come up with.

Comment: While technically a code optimization issue, questions like this (how to vectorize in `numpy`?) are routinely asked in SO.  It's really a 'how-to' question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
Result = Z[:,None,:,None,None] + Y[:,:,None,:,None] + X[:,:,:,None,:]
```

To produce this vectorized version, all I did was replace the various indices into `X`, `Y`, and `Z` with full `a,b,c,d,e`-style indexing, inserting `None` where missing indices were found. For example, `Y[a,b,d]` becomes `Y[a,b,None,d,None]`, which vectorizes into `Y[:,:,None,:,None]`.

In numpy, indexing by `None` tells the array to pretend like it has an additional axis. This doesn't change the size of the array, but it does change how operations get broadcasted, which is what we need here. Check out the [numpy broadcasting docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for more info.

Comment: Great answer. It would be good if you could also add a link to some documentation that describes the changes to broadcasting that this brings about.

Comment: 75 times faster with the parameters I have... thanks!